# Linux disc partition and Nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, partitioning, tornado

in the [linux bible book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470485051), i've found that it will be useful to install linux on different partitions; for example separating **/var** will be benefinc to avoid that an attacker will fill the hard drive and stops the OS (since the page will be in (**/var/www/**), and letting the application which is in **/usr** running,  (nginx for example) how can we do this?

am sorry for that question, because am new in linux system, when i've tried the first time to load another partition (the **d:** in windows), it asked me to *mount it first* (i've made a shortcut to a document in the **d:** and the shortcut dont work untill i mount the partition), so does it make sense to make 5 partitions (**/boot, /usr, /var, /home, /tmp**) to load the OS?

do the web hosters make the same strategy?

Comment: If you've got questions specific for the use of Linux, try http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://askubuntu.com. If the questions are specific for a (web) server, consider http://serverfault.com

Comment: but stackoverflow also can give the answer ^_^

Comment: SO is for programming-related questions. These sites I mentioned probably offer higher-quality answers, since they're targeted at a certain audience. Also, you've included several incomplete question-statements. what's your exact question?

Comment: my question was clear AFAIK ? sorry if my english is limited, but my question was : does it make sense to make 5 partition, every folder in a partition to make a good server security when using a webserver like nginx, and if the partitions exists, how the os can load them since they're not mounted yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

even you divide the partitions.

Attacker can fill the logs and make the web service unstable. Which mostly or defaultly located in /var/log folder. Some distros even log folder in /etc/webserver/log folder.

there are some uploading related flaws that made php upload features fill up the file limit on tmp folder.

This will not protect you at all. You must look the security from another perspective.

Comment: so the partition will only make a waste access time (since it must go for all partition and have a wasting time)

Comment: exactly. You have to look different aspects of security.Rather then partitioning. harning distro, more optimized services, remove unneaded modules from php/apache or whatever you use i mean there are million stuff. Filling var is not one of them. Every buddy is not try to take site down. Some ppl want to gain access in that is more dangerous then keeping the site up. These are all what i think. I hope you do best My friend.